# Bootstrap-Sprockets Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to implement bootstrap into my app and I keep getting a couple errors that I've never received when starting apps before. I browsed for an answer and the only answers I keep finding are to remove the `assets` part of the Gemfile which I don't have and to restart the server which I've done several times with no luck. Below are the errors and my files. Please let me know if something else needs to be provided. Thank you!

**Browser Error:** 
`File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets`

**Rails Server Warnings:**

```
/Users/tucker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:2: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::VERSION
/Users/tucker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:2: warning: previous definition of VERSION was here
/Users/tucker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.3.6/lib/bootstrap-sass/version.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant Bootstrap::BOOTSTRAP_SHA
/Users/tucker/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/bootstrap-4.0.0.alpha3/lib/bootstrap/version.rb:3: warning: previous definition of BOOTSTRAP_SHA was here
```

**Gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.5'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'pry'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

**Application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**Application.scss:**

```
...

*= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: try to remove all the comments from this file `application.scss` and leave only the two lines with `@import`

Comment: Thanks psantos! I just made those changes and it didn't work. I made an edit to my original post. I forgot to include other errors that were popping up in the rails server in case that helps make sense of this issue.

Comment: see the @Beniamin's answer. You dont need the `bootstrap` gem, only the `bootstrap-sass`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see you have `gem 'bootstrap'` and `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` in your gemfile. If you delete one of them, run `bundle` and follow the installation instructions on the respective github site then the sprockets should work. Also mine `application.scss` file is usually without the require part.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. The tutorial I was following had me include both but I can only assume that is an error.

Comment: Won't using `bootstrap-sass` instead of `bootstrap` mean that you're using bootstrap 3 and not 4?

Comment: jbk , you should post your answer as well, and it was informative comment is your comment.

Answer (score 2):

**1º)** Install the following gems in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

**2º)** Issue the following command:

```
mv app/assets/stylesheets/application.css app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
```

**3º)** Edit pp/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass and append the following lines:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
```

**4º)** Edit your app/assets/javascripts/application.js file and be sure it has the following lines:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**5º)** Now run

```
bundle install
```

And you are ready! This recipe always works for me and it is in [this site](https://launchschool.com/blog/integrating-rails-and-bootstrap-part-1).

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't understand a downvote to a correct answer. This won't work anymore because now we have Rails 5, but it was the correct answer at the time it was issued.  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Problem : file to import not found or unreadable bootstrap-sprockets

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

...........

solution :

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'

do bundle install

then restart your rails server