# Ruby on rails use devise display error on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise, display

I'm trying to deploy my app on Heroku, but there is an error.

I've tried to add `require 'devise'` in `config/application.rb` but it didn't work.

Link to the project on Github: https://github.com/qjpioneer/12in12-blog

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0', '>= 5.0.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'devise'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Error after `git push heroku master`**

```
Counting objects: 73, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
Writing objects: 100% (73/73), 518.43 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 73 (delta 41), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Using rack 2.0.1
remote:        Using nio4r 1.2.1
remote:        Using websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 7.1.2
remote:        Using json 2.0.2
remote:        Using mimemagic 0.3.2
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing rake 11.3.0
remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using subexec 0.2.3
remote:        Using pg 0.18.4
remote:        Using puma 3.6.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
remote:        Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.8
remote:        Using websocket-driver 0.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Using mini_magick 3.8.0
remote:        Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Using activesupport 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.1
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Using activemodel 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.6.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using activejob 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using activerecord 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using carrierwave 0.11.2
remote:        Using actionview 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actionpack 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actioncable 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using actionmailer 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using railties 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Installing warden 1.2.6
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using rails 5.0.0.1
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing responders 2.3.0
remote:        Installing devise 4.2.0
remote:        Bundle complete! 21 Gemfile dependencies, 67 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (6.31s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote:        Removing rake (11.2.2)
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
remote:        (sass):17
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:67:in `rescue in import'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:313:in `visit_import
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:65:in `import'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:28:in `imported_file'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:37:in `css_import?'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:313:in `visit_import
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sass-3.4.22/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:48:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_e0078c6c5e92289f77b7a5fa93263a6a/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to lit-cliffs-80047.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/lit-cliffs-80047.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/lit-cliffs-80047.git'
```

Comment: seems like you are importing a file in your sass which is not there

Comment: They key is this line, "Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets." Perhaps this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135126/sasssyntaxerror-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-bootstrap-sprockets , or this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880086/bootstrap-sprockets-error-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable-bootstrap-spr

Comment: Show your application.css.scss

Comment: i've deleted this app and start a new app

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the gem bootstrap-sass in your gemfile. Put `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`in your gemfile and `bundle`. This should fix your problem.